# Best way to store large amounts of form data in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design, serialization

I am doing a web app for a client that is an internal system for getting employees to fill out a multitude of forms before they start.

When I have received the forms, there are lots of them like 25-30, and i am having trouble figuring out how to store the data for each of them in a MySQL database. Each of the forms have different data required and different selections.

Initially i was thinking of having a single table, then serializing the selections into a column rather than having a hundred columns. I haven't done anything of this magnitude before and wondered what the best way to save the data would be?

Comment: Does it have to be MySQL? you could use a NoSQL database, such as MongoDB, which is schemaless...  http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless

Comment: Just on a standard Linux host and I am doing it with Codeigniter - not sure i will have rights to install MongoDB

Comment: Ah, that's a shame :-) would make your life a lot easier :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an EAV store, something like:

```
| form_name | employee_id | field_name | value |
```

It's not super clean but it's *kinda* normalized and you'll be able to query on it in a sane fashion. If you run into issues with the table being too large, even with indexes, you can split up the EAV store into multiple tables, possibly by form_name.

Comment: As a minor optimisation, you could move `form_name` and `employee_id` into a `submissions` table and tie those columns back with a `submission_id` column. Therefore, you would index only on the foreign key. `submission_id, field, value`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want at least three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE form_fields (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 form_name VARCHAR(50),
 field_name VARCHAR(20),
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `real_pk` (`formname`,`fieldname`)
);

CREATE TABLE forms_completed (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 form_name VARCHAR(20),
 ... other info about this instance of the form, 
         e.g. submitted date, submitted by...
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (form_name) REFERENCES form_fields(form_name)
                  ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE form_values (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 form_instance IN NOT NULL,
 form_name VARCHAR(50), /* only required to force referential integrity */
 field_name VARCHAR(20),
 date_value DATETIME,
 int_value INT,
 float_value FLOAT,
 string_value VARCHAR(100),
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (form_instance) REFERENCES forms_completed(id)
                  ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (form_name, field_name) 
      REFERENCES form_fields(form_name, field_name)
                  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not locked into MySQL, you can try doing this with MongoDB, as it is better suited for tasks like this one. If you are locked in, EAV is probably the way to go.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using this Data for maintaining records its a better idea to use MS Excel.
Or even you can try with the MS Access as alternative to it.

Comment: Please never recommend MS Access or MS Excel as a database solution for working with PHP or web development in general.

Comment: That was easier than I thought it would be. I thought I would have to go into a tirade of why you shouldn't recommend it. heh. good! :-)